# Рендер UI элементов асинхронно

Tags: c#, wpf, ui

Есть тяжелый UI внутри окна, пока он рендерится зависает все окно, как можно рендерить UI асинхронно, при этом не блокируя весь UI окна. Мои мысли ведут меня в асинхронность. Рендер тяжелый ибо происходит пересчет уже рендеренных элементов, `кол-во элементов = ширина окна / среднее арифметическое ширины всех уже зарендеренных`.

Comment: Вряд ли получится так прямо. Всё операции UI-объектами обязаны быть в UI-потоке. Вы уверены, что проблема именно в рендеринге? Может быть, имеет смысл ещё больше отделить контент от представления и вычислять в фоне всю тяжёлую математику?

Comment: @VladD сейчас начинаю "прокачивать" код, убирать все лишнее и обдумывать логику, понимаю, что скорее всего асинхронность может даже не понадобиться, много лишнего кода нашел и не ввел работу с буфером, а надо было.

Answer (score 1):

Создавать вручную в асинхронном потоке через `Dispatcher` и вставить в окно. Хотя стоит отметить, что это не чистый асинхронный поток, но он может решить проблему с одновременной работой в приложении.

```
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Content = "Click Me";

    sPanel.Children.Add(button);
});
```